# Codeigniter Multi-level Inheritance

Tags: codeigniter, inheritance, codeigniter-2

I am having problem in using multilevel inheritance as follows.

I have a top level controller that extends CI_Controller class

```
class Application extends CI_Controller
{
}
```

A controller named 'Site' and 'Admin' extends the Application controller as

```
class Site extends Application
{
}

class Admin extends Application
{
}
```

And finally class 'User' and 'Guest' extends 'Site' controller

```
class User extends Site
{
}

Class Guest extends Site
{
}
```

The problem is, in User and Guest controller I am not able to load core libraries such as pagination, form_validation etc. using

$this->load->library('pagination);

But it works when I load the library in Site controller or Application contoller ie. controller that extends the core CI_Controller and it's child controller. When I try to load in grand child it doesn't work.

Can somebody clarify why this is happening? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [CodeIgniter Base Controllers](https://github.com/sepehr/ci-base-controllers), explanation included.

Answer (score 2):

I've not seen a multi-level constructor class set up before, but it should work.

Are you calling `parent::__construct()` in the constructor of each class?

Comment: Yes, I am calling that. Only problem is that I am not able to load library from grand child.

Answer (score 0):

```
//-Create MY_Controller.php on application/core/MY_Controller.php
//contents of MY_Controller.php
class Application extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
      // Call the CI_Controller constructor
      parent::__construct();        
    }
}
//that is all now you can inherit class (Application) anywhere in your project
```